# building a complex listview

Tags: flutter, dart

[image: complex listview]

I'm new to flutter and I'm interested in how a composite listView can be built. Can you give a hint how you would make a similar element?

Comment: what have you tried so far? what does your code look like?

Comment: To be honest, I don't even know where to start

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Show the real design